# NoClassDefFoundError in Jadex

Tags: java

I'm using Jadex 0.96. I would like to use V2 but I could not get the current version to stably initialize the JCC on my Mac.

With Jadex 0.96, I am trying to use opencsv:

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

This requires me to add a .jar file to my project. I have some classes built that depend on opencsv that work fine when run in ordinary Java. However, when I try to initialize one of these classes in a Jadex plan, I get the following errors (omni0 is the name of the agent, DataGrid is the class that uses opencsv, and DataMap is a class that uses DataGrid):

```
***  Uncaught Exception for agent omni0  ***
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader
    at gi.environment.data.DataGrid.<init>(DataGrid.java:32)
    at gi.environment.data.DataMap.<init>(DataMap.java:46)
    at gi.agents.base.capabilities.interaction.InitialPlan.body(InitialPlan.java:39)
    at jadex.runtime.JavaStandardPlanExecutor$PlanExecutionTask.run(JavaStandardPlanExecutor.java:581)
    at jadex.util.concurrent.ThreadPool$ServiceThread.run(ThreadPool.java:308)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 5 more
```

I'm pretty confident that this has something to do with that included opencsv jar file but I have no idea how to get Jadex to recognize it. I tried adding it to the class path before initializing the DataMap with no luck:

```
System.setProperty("java.class.path",currentPath+opencsvPath);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line? Something like: `java -cp some.jar:opencsv-2.2.jar:bin YourMainClass`, for example, just to verify that the OpenCSV JAR is found. I've never used the system property myself: could that be a problem of absolute/relative path?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, the version of Jadex I'm using right now (EJADE) is tightly integrated with Eclipse, so running it from the command line is infeasible. I am using an absolute path to opencsv right now and have no idea what a relative path for an agent running in Jadex should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up writing my own simple `CSVDataReader` class to take the place of `CSVReader`. It works just as well for my application and avoids the Jadex errors that came from referencing a jar.

Here is the class in case anyone ever needs one:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVDataReader {

    private String filePath;

    public CSVDataReader(String filePath) throws IOException {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public List<String[]> readAll() throws IOException {
        // Get Buffered Reader
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Init lineList
        List<String[]> lineList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        // Get Lines
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)   {
            String[] strings = strLine.split(",");
            lineList.add(strings);
        }
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();

        return lineList;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        try {

            String filePath = "test.csv";

            CSVDataReader reader = new CSVDataReader(filePath);
            List<String[]> lineList = reader.readAll();

            for(String[] strings : lineList){
                for (String s : strings) {
                    System.out.print(s+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even am having same issue, i have `opencsv` defined but somehow it is not referenced, is there any other solution that worked for you?

Comment: I ended up using this solution too. the only problem is if words have double-quotes around them (which is a standard csv file).